# How to parse "Rain" from the OpenWeatherMap?

Tags: swift, xcode, openweathermap

When implementing Rain form the OpenWeatherMap API I run into this error:

'h' is not a valid digit in integer literal

I have a separate .swift document parsing all of the API references and have tried parsing Rain as this:

```
struct Rain: Decodable {
let 3h: Double?
}
```

but I'm not sure how to address "Rain: 3h" so the error doesn't occur.?

Can someone please take a look at the OpenWeatherMap API and let me know their thoughts?

**Updates:**

**struct.swift:**

```
struct Rain: Decodable {
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case threeHours = "3h" }

let threeHours: Double?
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
@IBOutlet weak var precipitation: UILabel!


let clouding = (self.rain?.threeHours!)!
precipitation.text = precipitation.text! + "  " + String(format:"%.0f", clouding)
```

Comment: Use `CodingKey`s as explained at [Ultimate Guide to JSON Parsing with Swift 4](https://benscheirman.com/2017/06/swift-json/)

Answer (score 1):

Just *translate* the key via CodingKeys

```
struct Rain: Decodable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case threeHours = "3h" }

    let threeHours: Double?
}
```

or

```
struct Rain: Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case h3 = "3h" }

    let h3: Double?
}
```

Comment: Or use the underscore `_3h`

Comment: @Carpsen90 Since, as I get told by so many old crusty ObjC developers, `_` tends to dictate "private", it may not be the best idea, also, it's not exactly readable, where as using `CodingKey`, you can make the name anything you want, making it much more readable and self documenting

Comment: @MadProgrammer that's true. The OP ran into an error by using an illegal variable name. Knowing that names should start with letters or underscores could be helpful.

Comment: @MadProgrammer it is just a name, like any other.

Comment: @Carpsen90 But will swift be able to map `_3h` to `3h` without `CodingKey`?

Comment: No no, of course the coding key should be used in this case. It was just a suggestion as close as possible to original code.

Comment: I see, any reason why I am getting Value of type 'WeatherDocument' has no member 'rain'; ?

Comment: I don't know which API you are using but for example if you receive `forecast` data the `rain` object is in the `list` array. And never force unwrap the value. If it won't rain the code crashes.